# Taxonomy view with attachment, only display 2nd level when parent is selected

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I got a taxonomy view like this, D7:

- Country 1

  - City 1
  - City 2
  - City 3
- Country 2

  - City 4
  - City 5

i managed to implement it using a block for first level "Taxonomy term: Parent term (= 0)" and a second level with a view via an attachment via a contextual filter "Taxonomy term: Name (translated)".
currently the whole tree is displayed, found tons of questions asking how to display first level only, my question is how to display only the selected second level. if i click "country 2", i'd only like to see City 4 & City 5 expanded, but 1-3 collapsed:

- Country 1
- **Country 2**

  - City 4
  - City 5